# Huawei DevEco IDE Chinese character problem

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I am trying to use DevEco IDE offered by Huawei to develop my application. Unfortunatelly my compilation fails due to my manifest contains garbled Chinese characters. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Post content of your Manifest file

Comment: Why does your manifest contain garbled Chinese characters?  Have you tried removing the garbled Chinese characters from your manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you downloaded the DevEco ide from China-Region link of course it will use some Chinese characters in it.

Non China Region Download Link : https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11297-deveco-ide-non-china-region-

Also you can fix this problem by clicking on
HUAWEI DevEco Studio->Help->Edit Custom VM Options

then
Add -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to Edit Custom VM Options

Do not forget to restart your IDE when you done with configuration.

Comment: thank you after editing my custom VM Options everything got resolved